# Get content nodes based on multiple content picker filters umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a document type called `Career Item` which contains some properties and 2 content pickers. one is for selecting a type of career: eg. Driver, the other one is for selecting a branch where the career will be placed: eg. Ghent Belgium.

My Career types and branches are located in a seperated `Content repository`, this means they do not have a template, its just a document with properties that can be used on several content pages.

I have created 2 filters for this and with some jQuery I managed to set the url based on the selection to get urls like:

```
http://localhost:59733/nl/vacatures/?f=1075&f=1076&b=1085&b=1082
```

Here you have `f` which contains the `Career type` Ids, and `b` which contains the `Branch` Id.

Now in my razor I am doing the filtering of the content nodes based on the selection but its quite messed up.

```
// Collect values for branch and function from the url querystring to perform filtering
var branch = umbraco.library.RequestQueryString("b"); // eg: 1085,1082 from example url above
var function = umbraco.library.RequestQueryString("f"); // eg: 1075,1076 from example url above

// Take the careers list content node
var careersList = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf("CareersList").FirstOrDefault();
var careerItems = careersList.Children.Where("Visible");

string query = "";
string funcQuery = "";
string branchQuery = "";

// Filter on fuction
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(function))
{
    // Property alias function: content picker
    string[] functions = function.Split(',');
    foreach (string func in functions)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(funcQuery))
        {
               funcQuery += " || function == \"" + func + "\"";
        }
        else
        {
               funcQuery = "function == \"" + func + "\"";
        }
    }
 }

  // Filter on branch
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(branch))
  {
       // Property alias branch: content picker
       string[] branches = branch.Split(',');
       foreach (string br in branches)
       {
             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(branchQuery))
             {
                  branchQuery += " || branch == \"" + br + "\"";
             }
             else
             {
                  branchQuery = "branch == \"" + br + "\"";
             }
       }
 }

 funcQuery = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(funcQuery) ? "(" + funcQuery + ")" : "";
 branchQuery = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(branchQuery) ? "(" + branchQuery + ")" : "";

 query = funcQuery + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(branchQuery) ? " && " + branchQuery : "");

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
 {
     careerItems = careerItems.Where(query);
 }
```

Am I missing something here and could this be simplified? Because now its only 2 filters, but what if i have 5 or 6 filters, then this is not workable...

/Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also maybe consider putting it all in an extension method for IPublishedContent called something like CheckFilters which accepts the arrays as parameters, so you can do something like:

```
var branches = Request.QueryString("b").Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var functions= Request.QueryString("f").Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var careerTypes = careersList.Where(a => a.IsVisible() && a.CheckFilters(branches, functions));
```

You can have all the logic in the extension method, and then it's easy to add additional filters, as you just modify the extension method, or add ne overloads.

You don't need to use the umbraco.library.RequestQueryString either, as it's just a wrapper for the Request.QueryString function.

Here's a very rough example of the Extension Method:

```
public static bool CheckFilters(this IPublishedContent content, string[] branches, string[] functions)
{
    return branches.Contains(content.GetPropertyValue<string>("branchPropertyAlias", "")) && functions.Contains(content.GetPropertyValue<string>("functionPropertyAlias", ""));
}
```

This is a pretty simple example that assumes that the content item only has one branch and one function.

Comment: Where do I need to add this extension method?

Comment: Either in App_Code or in your DLL for the site, if you have one with custom functions etc in. Do you know how to write extension methods in c#?

Comment: I have done it before, I will need to fresh it up but I will give it a go and see. If I get stuck I will get back to you. Thanks in advance

Comment: Tim, could you show an example of doing this? I have created a static class but now I need to create a static method to handle this. Also, is it possible to only allow this extension method to a particular node alias? Like in this example 'CareersList'?

Comment: Not sure how you'd limit the extension method to just one type, but I'll amend my answer to include an example Extension method.......

Comment: Never mind I got it working using an example on the umbraco forum. I would like to limit it to one alias because not all nodes need this filter method.

Comment: Limiting the extension method to certain node types isn't possible, as the extension applies to an object, regardless of the properties. You could however add some logic to the extension method so that it throws an error if you try and call it on the wrong node type, or something simlar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
var branch = "1085,1082";
var function = "1075,1076";

var careerTypes =
    careersList
        .Where(c => c.IsVisible() 
                    &&
                    branch.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
                          .Contains(c.GetPropertyValue<int>("branchId"))
                    &&
                    branch.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          .Select(b => int.Parse(b))
                          .Contains(c.GetPropertyValue<int>("functionId"))
              );

//branchId and functionId are the property names of those 2 content pickers
```